# declaring, initializing, and concatenating arrays issue

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to create a code and I keep getting compiler errors (just checking it, I'm not done).  What am I doing wrong:

```
if (numTeams = 20)
  Runner[] allRunners = ArrayUtils.addAll(team1.arrayRunners(), team2.arrayRunners(), 
  team3.arrayRunners(), team4.arrayRunners(), team5.arrayRunners(), team6.arrayRunners(),
  team7.arrayRunners(), team8.arrayRunners(), team9.arrayRunners(), team10.arrayRunners(),
  team11.arrayRunners(), team12.arrayRunners(), team13.arrayRunners(), team14.arrayRunners(),
  team15.arrayRunners(), team16.arrayRunners(), team17.arrayRunners(), team18.arrayRunners(),
  team19.arrayRunners(), team20.arrayRunners());
```

I have an import and declaration for ArrayUtils, is that fine?

I also have this earlier:

```
Runner [] allRunners = new Runner[numTeams*7];
```

numTeams is scanned in.

The errors I am getting are:

```
xcMeet.java:156: '.class' expected
      Runner[] allRunners = ArrayUtils.addAll(team1.arrayRunners(), team2.arrayRunners(),

xcMeet.java:156: not a statement
      Runner[] allRunners = ArrayUtils.addAll(team1.arrayRunners(), team2.arrayRunners(), 

xcMeet.java:156: illegal start of expression
      Runner[] allRunners = ArrayUtils.addAll(team1.arrayRunners(), team2.arrayRunners(),

xcMeet.java:156: ';' expected
      Runner[] allRunners = ArrayUtils.addAll(team1.arrayRunners(), team2.arrayRunners(),
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you add apache library

Comment: What is `ArrayUtils`? What does its `addAll` method do?

Comment: Add `{` and `}` to if statement. It is impossible (and have no sense) to have declaration statement as part of if statement.

Comment: I don't believe I have apache, how would I do that in jgrasp?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numTeams = 20)
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
if (numTeams == 20)
```

Beyond that I would need to see what team1... is.  It looks like they aren't classes, or aren't classes that have extended from an Object.

If I was you I would consider something that was team[x] instead of hard coding team1, team2, team3 as well.

-More-

Okay, I had to dig through some old code of mine, so lets see if this helps because I think this is similar to what you are doing.

This generated an ArrayList of ContentValues.  Number of items sent and of type type.

```
private ArrayList<ContentValues> wondrousCV(int number,ItemType type)
{
    ArrayList<ContentValues> list = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    ArrayList<String> wondrous_item = wondrous(number,type);
    ContentValues temp = null; //new ContentValues();
    if (wondrous_item != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < wondrous_item.size();i++)
        {
            temp = new ContentValues();
            temp.put("name", wondrous_item.get(i));
            temp.put("cost", -1);
            temp.put("type", "item");
            list.add(temp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list = null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

It was called from another function:

```
boolean generateTreasureCV(int value, TreasureType type)
{
    // List of strings generated to be the treasure
    treasureCV = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    ContentValues temp;

    treasureCV.addAll(wondrousCV(10,3));
    treasureCV.addAll(potionsCV(1,ItemType.LesserMinor));
    treasureCV.addAll(scrollsCV(1,ItemType.LesserMinor));
....}
```

So for your needs, your MasterRunners List would be similar to my treasureCV ArrayList but of type runner not ContentValues.  addAll only takes one ArrayList as a parameter so you will need to do something like

```
RunnersList.addAll(Team1.getRunners());
RunnersList.addAll(Team2.getRunners());
RunnersList.addAll(Team3.getRunners());
```

that's why I recommended you change to a Team[x] instead so you can loop through all your teams.

```
for (int I = 0; I < Team.sizeof; I++)
{
     RunnersList.addAll(Team[I].getRunners());
}
```

then if the number of teams you have varies you don't need different checks for every variable size

Comment: Yes, sorry about the =, I just forgot the other one.  But that didn't change my major errors.  Additionally, team is a class that I have coded separately, I can show it to you if you would like, but it compiles fine.

Comment: So from what I am seeing you have a class that contains an array of data.  From which you want to collect all those arrays into one.  Have you considered List instead or ArrayUtils.  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html but again your runners will probably need to extend Object.

Answer (score 0):

if its Apache's library then there is no such method(addAll) which can take var-args.
that method is overloaded but it can take max two parameters.